# In BigQuery, left join based on closest value

Tags: google-bigquery

```
with
    stats as (
        select 0.460 as stat1, 1.93 as stat2 union all
        select 0.482 as stat1, 2.17 as stat2 union all
        select 0.531 as stat1, 2.35 as stat2 union all
        select 0.477 as stat1, 1.83 as stat2 union all
        select 0.515 as stat1, 1.61 as stat2
    ),

    pctiles as (
        select 1 as pctile, .45 as stat1, 1.5 as stat2 union all
        select 2 as pctile, .46 as stat1, 1.6 as stat2 union all
        select 3 as pctile, .47 as stat1, 1.7 as stat2 union all
        select 4 as pctile, .48 as stat1, 1.8 as stat2 union all
        select 5 as pctile, .49 as stat1, 1.9 as stat2 union all
        select 6 as pctile, .50 as stat1, 2.0 as stat2 union all
        select 7 as pctile, .51 as stat1, 2.1 as stat2 union all
        select 8 as pctile, .52 as stat1, 2.2 as stat2 union all
        select 9 as pctile, .53 as stat1, 2.3 as stat2 union all
        select 10 as pctile, .54 as stat1, 2.4 as stat2 union all
    )
```

Is it possible to left join `pctiles` onto `stats`, using closest values in `pctiles`? We are seeking to assign a 1-10 `pctile` for each value & column in the `stats` table. Looking at the first row as an example with `select 0.460 as stat1, 1.93 as stat2`, we see in the `pctiles` table that 0.46 for `stat1` corresponds exactly with `2` as the pctile. For `1.93` and `stat2`, this is closest with `2.0` in the `pctiles` table which corresponds with a pctile of 6.

Our objective output for the "left join"

```
select 0.460 as stat1, 1.93 as stat2, 2 as pctile1, 6 as pctile2 union all
select 0.482 as stat1, 2.17 as stat2, 4 as pctile1, 8 as pctile2 union all
select 0.531 as stat1, 2.35 as stat2, 9 as pctile1, 9 as pctile2 union all
select 0.477 as stat1, 1.83 as stat2, 4 as pctile1, 4 as pctile2 union all
select 0.515 as stat1, 1.61 as stat2, 7 as pctile1, 2 as pctile2
```

For numbers in `stats` that fall exactly between two numbers in `pctiles` (eg. .515 is between 0.51 and 0.52), returning either `pctile` value 7 or 8 is fine.

Answer (score 2):

I see number of options  - consider below approach - somehow I ended up with it

```
select * except(id) from (
  select id, any_value(col) col, any_value(value) value, 
    array_agg(pctile order by abs(value - stat1) limit 1)[offset(0)] pctile
  from (select to_json_string(t) id, 'stat1' col, stat1 value from stats t) s 
  join pctiles p on col = 'stat1' group by id     
    union all 
  select id, any_value(col) col, any_value(value) value, 
    array_agg(pctile order by abs(value - stat2) limit 1)[offset(0)] pctile
  from (select to_json_string(t) id, 'stat2' col, stat2 value from stats t) s 
  join pctiles p on col = 'stat2' group by id
)
pivot (min(value) as stat, min(pctile) as pctile for replace(col, 'stat', '') in ('1', '2'))
```

if apply to sample data in your question - output is

[image]